Type checking issue when querying a database: properties field
When querying a database the response types are suggesting that 'properties' does not exist on 'PartialPageObjectResponse'
Property 'properties' does not exist on type 'PageObjectResponse | PartialPageObjectResponse | PartialDatabaseObjectResponse | DatabaseObjectResponse'.
  Property 'properties' does not exist on type 'PartialPageObjectResponse'

 const response = await notionClient.databases.query({
      database_id: databaseId,
      filter: {
        property: marketCode,
        select: {
          equals: market?.toLowerCase(),
        },
      },
    });

    const results = response.results[0]?.properties;

Below is the response when querying the database; you can see properties exist.
{
  object: 'page',
  id: '10...',
  created_time: '2024...',
  last_edited_time: '2024...',
  created_by: { object: 'user', id: '48e6f...' },
  last_edited_by: { object: 'user', id: '48e6...' },
  cover: null,
  icon: null,
  parent: {
    type: 'database_id',
    database_id: '10d...'
  },
  archived: false,
  in_trash: false,
  properties: {
    'Market...': { id: 'BMOO', type: 'select', select: [Object] },
    'Market...': { id: 'G%3DDn', type: 'select', select: [Object] },
    ...
  },
  url: 'https://www.notion.so/...',
  public_url: null
}

Is there a way to handle this, instead of me manually defining the response which seems unnecessary.
Thanks
Expecting properties to exist on the return type
